# Parallax transparent scrolling effect with "curtain" div placed outside the parallax div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm having problems making my "curtain" div transparent if it's outside the fixed DIV. In the example below I'd like to achieve transparency of the parallax-curtain DIV without having to place it inside the parallax DIV.

https://jsfiddle.net/0kfapw35/

I know it can be achieved if the DIVs are nested like so:

```
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax-curtain">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/jfxb0kz1/

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example is that if `parallax-curtain` is not a child of the `parallax` element, behind him it's only the `body` element, which is white. If your change the `body` element's `background-color:red;` you'll see that the transparency is indeed applied to `parallax-curtain`, it's just not visible in your example because it's the same color as the element behind him.

You can place the `parallax` element behind `parallax-curtain`, by adding `position:sticky; z-index=-1; top:0;`: https://jsfiddle.net/x837kwfb/60/

Comment: I was aware what was causing the problem but your solution is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!